# server path / vs \

Tags: file, unix, filesystems

In some documentation, I have gotten the instructions to write
SERVER_PATH\theme\

When I check _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] from php info, it's
/storage/content/75/113475/frilansbyran.se/public_html

this renders of course
/storage/content/75/113475/frilansbyran.se/public_html\theme\

this looks really weird to me what's the difference anyway which should I use? (unix-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backslashes is typically the windows way of paths, eg:

```
 C:\Windows\System32
```

Forward slashes are usually used in Unix systems ala:

```
 /usr/home/jdoe
```

If you are using a Unix-server I would stick to the forward slashes (/'s), though many times in in practice the system is smart enough to use either interchangeably

Comment: When I say system I mean using the wrong type of path within PHP or IIS (if on Windows), if you're at a unix shell the windows backslashes won't behave as you intend

Answer (score 1):

Path separator in Unix is `/`. The backslash `\` is used to escape some special characters (incl. space) in the directory and file names.

The backslash `\` is used as a path separator in the Windows world. It is possible, that 'some' documentation uses it.

If you are on Unix, use slash `/` only.

Answer (score 1):

In *nix, forward slash [`/`] is used as the directory separator, so I would use that.

Back slashes [`\`] are used as directory separators on Windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what others have said:

1. in URLs on the web, the Unix-style forward-slash `/` is always used; a backslash won't work in most situations.
2. in Windows filepaths, the forward-slash is an acceptable alternative to the backslash, so although it's not the normal way of writing it, `C:/Foo/Bar` will work.

So if in doubt, use the forward slash.