# How do I use dirname with PHP on IIS?

Tags: php, iis

I have a php program that uses:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/adLDAP.php");
```

but when I run it it comes out:

```
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp/../src/adLDAP.php Fatal error: 
Class 'adLDAP' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp\examples.php on line 12
```

How do I get the paths right on IIS with PHP?  I did not see anything in php.ini to set this.  I also tried to to use manually \ instead of / but it never sees the file.

This

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "\src\adLDAP.php");
```

gives this:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp\src\adLDAP.php
```

which is the right path but it never finds my class (I verified correct path with explorer copy and paste, it's there).  I put in a echo "HELLO"; to test but never echos.

What am I doing wrong so I can include the file.  Windows 7, IIS. Thank you.

It has include in front of it.  Added.

did not help:
[server path / vs \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918658/server-path-vs)

Comment: `(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/adLDAP.php");` won't do anything. Is there not something missing before that?

Comment: Neither does the string `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp/../src/adLDAP.php` return a fatal class not found. I think we're missing something here. By the way, Windows doesn't really bother about back or forward slashes. Both should work.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't undersatnd.  That line returns the error above.

Comment: How does the include itself do that? Maybe the code in that file is wrong? I'd expect a file not found, which you wouldn't get because of using `include` instead of `require`. If you get this message, it means that you're using code that uses a *class* that is not found.

Comment: That said: use `require` to include files you require. It will make it much easier to see if the file is indeed not found, or maybe there's another error.

Comment: You could use something like `echo "path: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/adLDAP.php")` to check that the file actually exists - an empty string means it doesn't. Generally speaking you might be better off with something like `require realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/adLDAP.php")` anyway as that'll certainly throw an error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: No worries - `realpath()` is your friend if you're developing on a Windows machine and deploying on a *nix one ;)

Answer (score 0):

adLDAP is namespaced.  Instead of:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP();
```

try:

```
$adldap = new \adLDAP\adLDAP();
```

or:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP\adLDAP();
```